# How to import and use com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachine

Tags: java, java-7, jdi

I found some classes designed for debugging in package `com.sun.jdi` like [VirtualMachine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html), but I can't use this because package seems not exist in Sun JDK7.

How to use this package?

BTW. `lib/sa-jdi.jar` isn't the same I want

Comment: according to [his link](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/com/sun/jdi/), `VirtualMachine` _is_ pat of JDK7

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [this page](https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/how_to_retrieve_remote_jvm), the `VirtualMachine` class that you linked to is part of the `tools.jar` file which is only distributed in a JDK (not a JRE). It says ...

> "**Update Note 2:** The Attach API is in tools.jar, so you will need to add /lib/tools.jar in your CLASSPATH to compile and run the example on JDK 6."

... and the same advice would apply on (at least) JDK 7 as well.